# How to detect resize of any element in HTML5

Tags: javascript, css, html

What should the best practices to listen on element resize event?

I want to re-position an element (jQuery dialog in my case), once it's size changed. But I am now more interested to do in a general way to to listen to resize event, unaware of how the resize happens. It suppose to be simple until I found an element can be re-sized by

- window resize
- content text changes
- children elements or their children elements resized
- a sibling element resize (e.g. a cell in a table)
- JavaScript changes it src(of img)/style attribute directly (or it's child's)
- JavaScript rewrite CSS rules or stylesheet
- native resize feature textarea or [CSS3 resize](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/resize)
- browser's zoom or text-enlarge
- CSS transition or animations (by :hover or any other mean)

In the de-facto standard, there is a event `window.onresize` to subscribe resize on a window/frame.
But there is no a standard event on the HTML content or DOM Elements.

I come across the following thought

- [DOM Level 3](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/) event target only on window/document type
- IE has [onresize](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536959(v=vs.85).aspx) for Elements but it is IE only implementation
- [MutationObserver](https://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#mutation-observers) which replace [Mutation Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Mutation_events), but it does not fit the need of "onresize"
- naive JavaScript polling

MutationObserver is close(inner DOM changes), but it does not (yet) cross browser (IE10 does not support) and it generate noise, not CSS aware.

A naive JavaScript polling should work in all case, but it generate either delay or CPU waste of many poll.

Comment: I posted an overview of libraries that do this at http://stackoverflow.com/q/37113134/1026

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As of July 2020, ResizeObserver is still un-official in W3C nor WhatWG but it is already supported by all major browsers since support Safari 13.1 since 2020-Mar-24.

---

FYI, there's a [spec](https://wicg.github.io/ResizeObserver/) for a new [ResizeObserver](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/10/resizeobserver) API. Chrome seems to be the only browser that has implemented it as of Aug 2018 (see [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/#feat=resizeobserver)), but there's at least one [polyfill](https://github.com/que-etc/resize-observer-polyfill) you can use now (which uses `MutationObserver`).

Answer (score 2):

Well, there is a easy library for that. Although there's nothing official how to listen on dimension changes of all types of elements and only `window` supports it at the moment we have luckily a polifill for that that works very accurate and supports all browsers even inclusive IE6+.

https://github.com/marcj/css-element-queries

You can find there a class `ResizeSensor`. To setup a listener on a element you can just do:

```
new ResizeSensor($('.myelements'), function() {
    console.log('changed');
});
```

Comment: I cannot get this to work on an element contained in a shadowroot.

Comment: I can't get this to work either. It does not fire if I change the dimensions of an element using JS or even if the element is responsive and changes dimensions due to window size change

Answer (score 2):

Given yourelement, when the size changes (ex. a text translation took place) you can doyourstuff(), including
    ro.unobserve(yourelement);

```
  var inilen = yourelement.offsetWidth;
  var ro = new ResizeObserver( entries => {
    for (let entry of entries) {
      const cr = entry.contentRect;
      if (inilen !== cr.width) {
        doyourstuff();        
      }
    }
  });

  ro.observe(<your element>);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is not simple solution, that's not good.

I've found something very useful for this.: [cross browser event based element resize](http://www.backalleycoder.com/2013/03/18/cross-browser-event-based-element-resize-detection/)

It's tricky, appending some needed html to the element that have to be listened and detects scrolling event.

**Some html example from that page:**

```
<div class="resize-triggers">
    <div class="expand-trigger"><div></div></div>
    <div class="contract-trigger"></div>
</div>
```

**Also Some JS:**

```
var myElement = document.getElementById('my_element'),
    myResizeFn = function(){
        /* do something on resize */
    };
addResizeListener(myElement, myResizeFn);
removeResizeListener(myElement, myResizeFn);
```

But it works for elements those are able to have children, not for self-closing tags.

You can see the demo http://jsfiddle.net/3QcnQ/67/

Comment: only if it helps :)))

Comment: Where does `addResizeListener` and `removeResizeListener` functions come from? The answer doesn't provide the entire solution. It's a bad practice to hide vital information behind links, because they could break in the future.

Comment: HI @SlavaFominII agree but, I could not just copy whole article from the link though,   but I could add it as comment as well. Noted and will consider in the future. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the future, we may have the luxury of the `ResizeObserver` everywhere, but for less recent browsers in 2021 we need to make do with a workaround. [This article](http://www.backalleycoder.com/2013/03/18/cross-browser-event-based-element-resize-detection/) has already been posted, but it's pretty old and I think the solution might be overly complicated for modern browsers.

Still, the core idea remains: add an `<object>` element as a child with `width: 100%; height: 100%;`, and set a `resize` listener on its inner `window` object.

Here's some demo code that works in the latest Chrome and Firefox:

```js
const div = document.getElementById('demo')
const obj = document.createElement('object')
obj.className = 'resize-detector'
obj.type = 'text/html'
obj.data = 'about:blank'
obj.addEventListener('load', function() {
  // Initialize once.
  handleResize()
  // Add resize handler on the <object>'s inner window.'
  obj.contentWindow.addEventListener('resize', function() {
    handleResize()
  })
})
div.appendChild(obj)

function handleResize() {
    document.getElementById('size').innerHTML = `${div.offsetWidth}×${div.offsetHeight}`
}
```

```css
.resizable {
  /* Make this the offset parent of the <object> */
  position: relative;
}

#demo {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #def;
  /* Allow user resizing, for testing. */
  resize: both;
  overflow: hidden;
}

object.resize-detector {
  display: block;
  visibility: hidden;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="demo" class="resizable">
  <div id="size"></div>
</div>
```

It doesn't work inside the StackOverflow snippet because of some same-origin policy shenanigans, but [here's a JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hyzqgks4/) with the same code.