# Detect when a DIV's height changes without polling or mutation observers

Tags: javascript

I need to get the height of a `div` and get notified when its height changes according to data.

I am using `getBoundingClientRect()` to get the height currently, but I don't get notified of any further changes.

I also tried `DOMAttrModified` and `MutationObserver` to detect changes in the data, but both of them are not universally supported in all browsers.

What's the best way to get notifications about changes to an element's height?

Comment: Can you show your codes ?

Comment: Welcome to SO, please take a tour of the help centre and see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 3):

The idea (that seems to originate from a [blog post on backalleycoder.com](http://www.backalleycoder.com/2013/03/18/cross-browser-event-based-element-resize-detection/)) is that you can use

- `onresize` on the element itself in IE <=10.
- `scroll` events on a specially crafted `<div>` appended as a child of the element in most other browsers
- or `onresize` on `<object style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; height: 100%; width: 100%;">` appended as a  child of the element.

There's a number of libraries that implement some or all of these approaches:

- [sdecima/javascript-detect-element-resize](https://github.com/sdecima/javascript-detect-element-resize) - uses `onresize` in IE + `scroll` in other browsers. Small (5KB unminified), but not actively maintained ATM.
- [wnr/element-resize-detector](https://github.com/wnr/element-resize-detector): uses the same idea, but is more actively maintained, also available as an NPM package. It has the nicest readme, explaining the [caveats](https://github.com/wnr/element-resize-detector#caveats) and explaining that the resize-on-`<object>` technique is only truly needed in certain older browsers. The author even wrote a paper about this ([Modular Responsive Web Design using Element Queries](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.01223v1.pdf)). The library is quite larger (16KB minified!) (probably because it's written in a *less ad-hoc* way -- for example it has a "batchProcessorMaker" to allow running a number of functions at a later stage.)
- http://marcj.github.io/css-element-queries/ provides a `ResizeSensor`
  class that appears to use the same `scroll` technique (from another popular SO question: [How to detect DIV's dimension changed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6492683/how-to-detect-divs-dimension-changed)). The rest of library has a different purpose, though.

Note that older questions here on SO talk about:

- [`attrchange`](http://meetselva.github.io/) in jQuery, DOMAttrModified, etc. - that won't help you with detecting height changes that do not involve changing the `height` attribute
- DOMSubtreeModified, MutationObserver - can be used to detect changes in *content* (which is one of the reasons that can lead to height changes -- the other being layout changes, such as a change to the width)
- older solutions, including some jQuery plugins that use polling to accomplish this -- that's not a recommended solution, because the page will waste the user's battery even when nothing is resized.

[edit] [ResizeObserver](https://github.com/WICG/ResizeObserver/blob/master/explainer.md) will allow to detect this without hacks in newer browsers.