# Callback after External Elements in innerHTML are loaded

Tags: javascript, html

I have a string in javascript that I want to use to instantiate a child element for a particular element, eg:

````
let target = document.getElementById("target")
let string = ```
    <div>
        <img src="somewhere">

        <h1> This is a heading </h1>

        <p> And some text <p>
    </div>
```
target.innerHTML = string
````

Later, I want to find the offset of the heading:

```
// ...
// later
// ...

let heading = target.getElementByTagName("h1")
console.log(heading.offsetTop)
```

But sometimes its incorrect because sometimes the image (or any other external element) has loaded, and sometimes it hasn't loaded before I find the offset. Can anybody suggest a **jquery free** way to determine when the contents of `target` have finished loading all external resources?

Comment: Add an onload-listener to the image, and do what you need in the handler function.

Comment: try: `image.onload = function() { /* ... */ }`. this will trigger when the image is fully loaded and you can read out the offset

Comment: What about other elements that might need to load. An image is just a typical example.

Comment: Well, you are asking about `img`, right?, and not all elements have an _onload_ event, these does `<body>, <frame>, <iframe>, <img>, <input type="image">, <link>, <script>, <style>`

Comment: Would it be enough to subscribe to all of the onload events for all children that are of these types?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend to subscribe to all, just those you need.

Comment: But would it be only the tags you've listed above to worry about? I'm worried about any tags that will "change size" once any external content has been loaded, because it will mess up any scrolling events I have.

Comment: Well, that is way out of scope for this question. Read this (and check `MutationObserver` in the question): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25679784/how-to-detect-resize-of-any-element-in-html5

Comment: I did already try a MutationObserver, but it didn't seem to do anything when the image loaded. Could have been a mistake in my implementation.

Comment: It appears to me the issue you have is more about _...once any external content has been loaded, it might mess up any scrolling events_ than when an image been loaded.

Comment: Yep, that is the problem I'm having :) This is better wording

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet is probably to add a `load` listener to each of the loadable items
in your target and then fire a callback when they have all loaded.

```js
let onReady = (target, callback) => {
  // add any other tags you have that need to load to the selector
  // i.e. querySelectorAll('img, iframe'), etc.
  let loadables = [...target.querySelectorAll('img')];

  let total = loadables.length;
  let doneCount = 0;

  // since I'm using bind this needs to be a normal function, not an arrow function
  let loadObserver = function() {
    // remove the listener since we don't need it anymore
    this.removeEventListener('load', loadObserver);
    doneCount += 1;
    if (doneCount === total) {
      callback();
    }
  };

  loadables.forEach(el => {
    el.addEventListener('load', loadObserver.bind(el), true);
  });
};


  let target = document.getElementById("target");
  let string = `
  <div>
      <img id="i1" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x50">
      <img id="i2">
      <img id="i3">
      <h1> This is a heading </h1>

      <p> And some text <p>
  </div>
  `;
  target.innerHTML = string;

  // note that you have to call onReady right away after setting the
  // innerHTML, since JS is single threaded calling it now will add the
  // load listeners before any of the images start to load. If you call
  // it later, after the event loop has run, it might not work.
  onReady(target, () => {
    let heading = target.querySelector("h1");
    console.log(heading.offsetTop);
  });






// simulate slow loading images
let loadAfter = (el, ms) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
     el.src = 'http://via.placeholder.com/350x50';
  }, ms);
};

loadAfter(document.getElementById('i2'), 2000);
loadAfter(document.getElementById('i3'), 3000);
```

```css
img {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background: #ccc;
}

#target {
  border: 1px dashed #f00;
}
```

```html
<div id="target"></div>
```

A couple of other things to note about your code, in JS [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) just have a single backtick unlike HEREDOCs in other languages that require 3. Also you used the nonexistent  `getElementByTagName` method. There is a `getElementsByTagName` method (note the *s* in *Elements*), but it returns a collection, not a single node. You could use `target.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0]` to get the element you are looking for, but instead in my code I used [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector), which always returns a single element.

Comment: Yep, this is basically what I ended up doing. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score -1):

```
"<img src='somewhere' onload='imageIsLoaded(this.id)'>"
```

imageIsLoaded() can be a javascript function.

Comment: Jquery free please :P Can't add jquery to this project. But yes, this sort of functionality.

Comment: oh my bad. if you want jquery free then you can add `onload` event listener..see the updated answer.